# Is there a program that tracks the running times of computer games?

Tags: pc

I think I spend way too much time on computer games and would like to know exactly how much time I spend on them, in hopes that this will help me refrain myself from playing...

Is there a program that can give me a detailed report on how long these game processes run per day?

Comment: Doesn't Steam do this?

Comment: @Pubby8: It does, yes. Not sure if it works in offline mode.

Comment: There is.. It's called a girlfriend.

Comment: Nor does Steam help for non-steam games (yes, it can launch them, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't track playtime etc).

Comment: i also find that steam gets it wrong quite often.

Comment: @Bora I installed the upgrade to girlfriend, WIFE, and now my gaming time is down to near 0 :-(

Comment: @Bora, it may save me time, but it'll help me lose money.

Comment: This sounds more like a [SU] question to me.

Comment: @MatthewRead: It's a bit on the edge. Could as well stay here, it has to do with gaming, after all.

Comment: For consoles, certain TVs has a display mode which displays the amount of time played at every half hour interval,

Comment: If you're on Windows 8 or later, you can use the Task Manager (Ctrl + Shift + Esc). Simply go to "*App history*". Make sure you've checked "*Show history for all processes*" under "*Options*". The CPU time will give you a rough estimate of how long the game was running. However, CPU time depends on the CPU load. If your game doesn't put a lot of load on your CPU, the value might be much lower than you'd expect. If the game makes use of multiple cores, it could even exceed your expectations. For instance, a game that constantly puts 100% load on 2 cores will read 2 hours for every hour you play

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's [ManicTime](http://www.manictime.com/). It's great... and comes with a free usable version. It's stored in a local database...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Well there is Raptr.com and the downloadable client that tracks the amount of time you play a game not very detailed but it just counts the hours you play for each game.

Comment: I checked this site, unfortunately it gives incentives to play, so it's unacceptable, sorry.

Comment: incentives to play? as far as I know it just shows you what you've earned in the game and just records it.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try [Wakoopa](http://social.wakoopa.com/). It monitors all running apps in your system, including games.

Answer (score 2):

[XFire's client](http://www.xfire.com) will do this for you. They also provide game time profile images that you can add to forum signatures and other websites.

Comment: I checked this site, unfortunately it gives incentives to play, so it's unacceptable, sorry.

Comment: and they closed the service now.

Answer (score 0):

[TimeSnapper](http://www.timesnapper.com/) does this and it also takes screenshots periodically. (I remember this working quite well even for games, e.g. Left 4 Dead.)

Answer (score 0):

I use [RescueTime](https://www.rescuetime.com/), it's cross platform, online, lets you set targets and even gives you a weekly summary email.

I've been using it for years and, even if the Sunday evening productivity emails can sometimes be depressing, I think it's helped me strike the right balance between games and work.